# Android log message "InputMethodManager: The current service view is not the focus view"

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-anr-dialog

While running my android app I see the following warning-level message in the logs right before the app generates an ANR popup warning:

"InputMethodManager: The current service view is not the focus view"

I get the message when clicking on an edittext field in the UI. What causes that warning message?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific or code piece will help, as this does not seem to be only due to EditText.

Comment: Add some of code and log with this question

Comment: can you please add logs and trace.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually ANR happens when you do some long running job in UI thread(request server/database, wait some event with sleep, etc).

About your warning, maybe you call request focus on another view, when some events happened. Try to comment some logic of you service and check behaviour.